# Android Email Programmatic Setup

Tags: android

I have performed some initial research, but have not found exactly what I am looking for (yet).

I wanted to know if it is even possible to either set up or modify email account settings programmatically.  I do not believe it is, due to email applications controlling their own settings (and thus would depend upon a ContentProvider from that specific client), but I have not yet found a definitive "no", either.

Further, I was wondering about the email account support on Android in general.  It appears that Android 2.0 and above will allow for multiple ActiveSync/Exchange accounts and mulitple IMAP/POP3 accounts, and displays these in the same inbox.  Is this claim true?  Also, how is this different from the other major Android releases (Android 1.5 and 1.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not believe it is, due to email
>   applications controlling their own
>   settings (and thus would depend upon a
>   ContentProvider from that specific
>   client), but I have not yet found a
>   definitive "no", either.

Hmmmm...not sure how to get "definitive" styling on SO here... :-)

Your analysis is correct, and there is no central repository for email accounts per se.

> Is this claim true?

There definitely is support for multiple protocols, and I'm fairly certain there is support for multiple accounts per protocol. However, I do not use the built-in email client.

> Also, how is this different from the
>   other major Android releases (Android
>   1.5 and 1.6)?

Exchange support was not built into Android until 2.x. HTC had some devices with Exchange support before that, but it was their own implementation.